# search the database for the words within a string

Tags: c#, linq

Imagine that a user entered a sentence and I need to search for the subjects that consist of words within the entered sentence. These are the code that I thought they could solve the case.

```
var result = from x in dataBase.tableName 
             select x;

string[] words = enteredString.Split(); 

foreach(string word in words) 
            {
                result = result.Where(x => x.subject.Contains(word));
            }
```

it shows only the search result with the last word in sentence, but I thought the result must be narrowed down each time a word is used in the where line.

Comment: What you've given *should* work... how are you displaying the results? Have you debugged into it to see that `Where` is being called multiple times?

Comment: It looks like it should do the thing. You should start by putting a breakpoint and stepping the code. What is the content of `words`? You can also type in `database.Log = Console.Out;` and watch the outputwindow for the resulting SQL query. Is the query what you expect?

Comment: You're [closing over the loop variable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) when you're constructing your where clauses in your query.  So it effectively filters only the last item.

Comment: Could you tell me where can I see the output of your code Albin?

Comment: @Daniel, menu Debug->Windows->Output

Comment: @Jeff, sharp spotted, you should make that an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach(string word in words) 
{
  var temp = word;
  result = result.Where(x => x.subject.Contains(temp));
}
```

This is called (by ReSharper at least) "access to modified closure" - lambda expressions don't capture the **value**, they capture the entire **variable**.  And the value of the variable `word` is changing with each iteration of the loop.  So, since the Where() method is lazy-evaluated, by the time this sequence is consumed, the value of `word` is the last one in the sequence.

Comment: I tried your code but when more than one word is entered, it doesn't show anything....

Comment: that's because result gets set with the result for first word, then the subsequent searches only search within the previous result and overwrite it...

Comment: thx Yahia, but do you have any solution for my problem? how can I narrow down the result?

Comment: @Yahia I don't believe that's a problem. If he's looking for only the entities where `subject` contains ALL the words in the collection, which I think is the goal, then each re-definition of `result` should just further refine the result set, i.e. first you get all entities that have word1 in their title, then those that have word1 and word2, etc

Comment: @Paul: I am not sure whether he wants a result where any OR all words are present...

Comment: @Yahia all words must be in the search result

Comment: @Daniel this is an embarrassingly simple suggestion, and I'm grasping at straws, but are you sure you entered a combination of words that actually exists in one subject in your database? If so, there is some other problem that I can't diagnose from this.

Comment: @Daniel: must all words be in the SAME subject/record ?

Comment: then the answer of @Paul is correct... and you don't seem to have any records in your DB matching the word list you tried or there is a "case-sensitivity" issue...

Comment: @Yahia as paul said it has an easy solution but I don't know what is wrong. the record exists and case sensitive is not an issue. I think I need to review all your comments once more to figure out the answer

Answer (score 2):

I hade some success by inverting the logic like this:

```
string[] words = enteredString.Split();

var results = from x in database.TableName
              where words.Any(w => x.subject.Contains(w))
              select x;
```

-- Edit
A more generic approach, for this kind of queries, would be:

```
class SearchQuery
{
    public ICollection<string> Include { get; private set; }
    public ICollection<string> Exclude { get; private set; }
}

[...]
SearchQuery query = new SearchQuery
{
    Include = { "Foo" }, Exclude = { "Bar" }
}

var results = from x in database.Table
              where query.Include.All(i => x.Subject.Contains(i)) &&
                    query.Exclude.All(i => !x.Subject.Contains(i))
              select x;
```

This assumes that all words in query.Include must occur in `Subject`, if you want to find any subjects that have at least one of the words `query.Include.All` should be `query.Include.Any`

I've tested this with Entity Framework 4. Which will create a SQL query that applies all criteria in the database rather than in memory.

Comment: it is working Tihon but could you tell me how can I use your code separately, I mean how can I get the result first and then use your solution to narrow down the result.

Comment: @Daniel I think if you changed `words.Any` to `words.All` it might do the trick

Comment: @Daniel Can you provide more details, on what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have about 500 cases and in the search section of my application users can look for the cases by entering some words. All these words must exist in the found cases. but the problem is that the result with all cases are coming from other part of the application and I just can narrow them down.

Comment: Did you try using words.All instead of word.Any as Paul Equis suggested?

Comment: Does "words" by any chance contains empty strings or single white-spaces? The String.Split methods accepts a System.StringSplitOptions value that allows you to filter empty strings from the resulting array.

Comment: yes they are separated by space. I checked and they were extracted from string correctly but the search doesn't show what I need

Comment: @Daniel let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2457/discussion-between-j-tihon-and-daniel)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
var result = from x in dataBase.tableName 
             select x;

string[] words = enteredString.Split(); 
result.Where(r => words.Any(w => r.Subject.Contains(w));
```

Answer (score 0):

it can't do the thing - since with every word you are overwriting the previous `result` - you need to do something similar to:

```
List<object> AllResults = new List<object>();

foreach(string word in words) 
{
  var temp = word;
  AllResults.AddRange (result.Where(x => x.subject.Contains(temp)).ToList());
}
```

Not sure what type your result type is hence the `List<object>`...

Comment: Sorry Yahia but I knid of need to get the result in IEnumerable and I don't know how to convert the result of your solution to IEnumerable

Comment: ok - then scratch my solution... if you need all words in the every result record then use Paul Equis solution because that's what his solution does...